# How to suggest files with tab completion using readline?

Tags: node.js, readline, tab-completion

Within the Bash shell, I can use tab-completion to use suggest file and directory names. How can I achieve this with nodejs and [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options)?

Examples:

- `/<Tab>` should suggest `/root/`, `/bin/`, etc.
- `/et<Tab>` should complete to `/etc/`.
- `fo<Tab>` should complete to `foobar` assuming such a file exists in the current directory.

I was thinking of using globbing (pattern `search_term.replace(/[?*]/g, "\\$&") + "*"`), but is there maybe a library that I have overlooked?

This is my current approach using glob, it is broken when using `//<Tab>` as it returns the canonicalized name and has possibly some other oddities:

```
function command_completion(line) {
    var hits;
    // likely broken, one does not simply escape a glob char
    var pat = line.replace(/[?*]/g, "\\$&") + "*";
    // depends: glob >= 3.0
    var glob = require("glob").sync;
    hits = glob(pat, {
        silent: true,
        nobrace: true,
        noglobstar: true,
        noext: true,
        nocomment: true,
        nonegate: true
    });

    return [hits, line];
}

var readline = require("readline");
rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    completer: command_completion
});
rl.prompt();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution with a few quirks:

- It doesn't support relative paths
- When trying to display suggestions by pressing tab twice, it displays the full path in the list of suggestions.
- It prefers '/' over '\', but tolerates '\' separators on windows
- It only supports directories and files. (no devices, pipes, sockets, soft links)

Code:

```
const { promises: fsPromises } = require("fs"); 
const { parse, sep } = require("path");

function fileSystemCompleter(line, callback) {
  let { dir, base } = parse(line);
  fsPromises.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
    .then((dirEntries) => {
      // for an exact match that is a directory, read the contents of the directory
      if (dirEntries.find((entry) => entry.name === base && entry.isDirectory())) {
        dir = dir === "/" || dir === sep ? `${dir}${base}` : `${dir}/${base}`;
        return fsPromises.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
      }
      return dirEntries.filter((entry) => entry.name.startsWith(base));
    })
    .then((matchingEntries) => {
      if (dir === sep || dir === "/") {
        dir = "";
      }
      const hits = matchingEntries
        .filter((entry) => entry.isFile() || entry.isDirectory())
        .map((entry) => `${dir}/${entry.name}${entry.isDirectory() && !entry.name.endsWith("/") ? "/" : ""}`);
      callback(null, [hits, line]);
    })
    .catch(() => (callback(null, [[], line])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look on readdir: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readdir

Just read the directory on which the user is making a tab, then compare the user input with the beginning of each file on the directory and if a filename match, display it to the user. Something like:

```
var readDir = require('readdir');

function strncmp(str1, str2, lgth) {
  var s1 = (str1 + '')
    .substr(0, lgth);
  var s2 = (str2 + '')
    .substr(0, lgth);

  return ((s1 == s2) ? 0 : ((s1 > s2) ? 1 : -1));
}

var userInput = // get user input;
var path = // get the path;
readDir.read(path, [*], function(err, files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        if (strncmp(files[i], userInput, userInput.length) == 0)
            console.log(files[i]);
});
```